# Preserving white space when using .split?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, whitespace

I am trying to split a string and store this in an array, such that each word is stored at a separate index. I also want the white space and any punctuation to be stored.

eg. "Hello world!"

would be stored as:

```
array[0]: "hello"
array[1]: " "
array[2]: "world!"
```

I am currently using .split but can't figure out how to split the string so that it splits at the end of the word **and** stores the white space.

```
strArray = str.split(" ");
```

Comment: Can you give an example why you need this? I don't know what this is supposed to be good for... or at least I think that's not the way to go

Comment: You can split on word boundary `"\\b" `, though the sentence either starts with a word, or white space. Then you could use regex look-ahead/behind to the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add space to every element except of the last one

```
String token=" ";
strArray = str.split(token);

for(int i=0;i<strArray.length - 2 ;i++){
  strArray[i]=strArray[i]+token
}
```

Comment: Would miss to preserve more than one space in `hello    world` (in case keeping them is relevant)

Comment: so the token is no " " but "\s+"

Comment: or even "(\s+") so you can add whole capture group

Comment: Also this would store two tokens `["hello  ", "world]` instead of three.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

The constructor [StringTokenizer(String str, String delim, boolean returnDelim)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) is handy for this.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(args[1], args[0], true);
        ArrayList<String> sa = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            sa.add(st.nextToken());
        String[] array = sa.toArray(new String[sa.size()]);
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
            System.out.println(String.format("array[%d] = '%s'", i, array[i]));
    }
}

$ java Test " " "a test"
array[0] = 'a'
array[1] = ' '
array[2] = 'test'

$ java Test " " "a  test"
array[0] = 'a'
array[1] = ' '
array[2] = ' '
array[3] = 'test'
```

What you would do, probably, is test each element of the array to determine if it is or is not a delimiter, which is not difficult considering the knowledge of the delimiter argument to the constructor.

Comment: Which one? You might want to expand on this to improve the quality of your answer, see [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You can also always split the string yourself.

```
import java.util.*;

class Split {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        var s = new Split();
        System.out.println(s.split(args[0]));
    }

    private List<String> split(String word) {
        // TODO: validate empty string
        var list = new ArrayList<String>();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var inSpace = word.charAt(0) == ' ';

        for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {

            if (c == ' ' && inSpace || c != ' ' && !inSpace) {
                sb.append(c);
            }
            if (c == ' ' && !inSpace || c != ' ' && inSpace) {
                list.add(sb.toString());
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(c);
                inSpace = !inSpace;
            }
        }

        list.add(sb.toString());
        return list;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
~/$ java Split "hello world" 
[hello,  , world]
~/$ java Split "hello         world"
[hello,          , world]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to split the string and keep the delimiters using regular expressions, lookahead and lookbehind may be needed: [`(?=\W)|(?<=\W)`](https://regex101.com/r/rlmMlF/1/), that is, the split is done by an empty string following to or followed by a non-word character:

```java
String str = "Hello    World!";

Arrays.stream(str.split("(?=\\W)|(?<=\\W)"))
      .forEach(s -> System.out.println("'" + s + "'"));
```

Output:

```java
'Hello'
' '
' '
' '
' '
'World'
'!'
```

---

Simpler version would be to split by word border `\b` as suggested in the comment, then all delimiters are joined:

```java
String str = "Hello    World!";
Arrays.stream(str.split("\\b"))
      .forEach(s -> System.out.println("'" + s + "'"));
```

Output:

```
'Hello'
'    '
'World'
'!'
```